# Update on GridView combobox not updating

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to bind the DropDownList(DDL) with my entity datasource. The GridView(GV) is bound to a different EntityDataSource than the DDL. The GV's EntityDataSource has a navigation property 'Bag' for the relationship. In edit mode I can pick a different item, but it does not update the database for that record. I did use the *include* for the navigations in the EntityDataSource. I am sure the wiring is not correct. I have tried searching with no luck so far. Thanks for the help.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bag">
  <ItemTemplate >
    <asp:Label ID="lbEditBag" Text='<%#Eval("Bag.Item1") %>' runat="server" />
  </ItemTemplate>
  <EditItemTemplate >
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlBags" DataSourceID="edsBags" DataTextField="Amount" DataValueField="BagId" />
  </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: have you tried to enclose your `Gridview` to an `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: Will try that. So is the wiring up look ok?

Comment: Do you have an existing action for your DDL? include the `UpdatePanel` to your `PostBackTrigger`.

Comment: Adding the Update Panel did not help. I have not worked with PostBackTriggers - will look into it.

Comment: Why can't I set the SelectedValue on the DDL - it's not even an option??? All the stuff I find has the binding to this - much like windforms does. WTF!

Comment: Do you add an action if the `SelectedValue` is changed?

Comment: No, what do I need to do here - selectedIndexChanged event?

Comment: in the selectedIndexChanged, do what you want to happen on update. for example, reload the gridview with the corresponding new values.

Comment: Not following what your saying. The databinding should be taking care of the data being changed - if wired correctly. What I did was bind the ddl's datasource to a diff EDS(related table) for it's values for the ddl instead of the original table that holds the records. I just can't wrap my head around what to change when the user selects a diff item - what tells the datasource to update this field? Thanks for your help so far...

Answer (score 0):

DonA, if you've not found your answer yet I will explain what I have done to do something similar to what your after I believe.

In a gridview I have various asp:TempleteField's, one which is like this:-

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="lblActive" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Active") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<%--<asp:TextBox ID="txtboxActive" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Active") %>'     Width="20px" TextMode="SingleLine" CssClass="textboxEdit"></asp:TextBox>--%>
<asp:DropDownList ID="activeDDL" CausesValidation="False" AutoPostBack="False"     runat="server">                      <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

which as you can see has two dropdownlist items in the EditItemTemplete (I also left in similar code to yours that I used to use to bind to a database for the DDL values but I don't use anymore so is commented out)

then alongside the ID, runat="server", DataKeyNames, etc. in

```
<asp:Gridview ID=""...
```

i have

```
OnRowUpdated="info_GridView_RowUpdated"
```

This then runs in my C# code behind an SQL function to update the database table with the setting from the DDL, like so (I have also put in a few other Gridview.Databind() to reset my other gridviews)

```
protected void info_GridView_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    // The update operation was successful. Retrieve the row being edited.
    int index = info_GridView.EditIndex;
    GridViewRow row = info_GridView.Rows[index];
    int itemID = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Text); // Cells[4] is only one available as others are being edited!

    // update Active value in the database //
    comm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Products SET Active=@active WHERE ItemID=@itemID", objConn);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@active", ddlValue); // this stores DDL value in database
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemID", itemID);// Convert.ToInt32(propertyRefTextBox.Text));

    objConn.Open();
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    objConn.Close();

              // force update and reset selectedIndex of other gridviews //
    Category_GridView.DataBind();
    editImages_GridView.DataBind();

    Category_GridView.SelectedIndex = -1;
    editImages_GridView.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

}

hope the above helps.

Trev.